# How implement a python function with different parameter types

Tags: python, duck-typing

I need to implement a two parameters function with python. The parameter types can be: (String, String), (String, List) or (List, List). In Java I would use overloading to manage this situation but in python I just can think in the next solution:

```
def myFunction(param1, param2):
     if isinstance(param1, basestring) and isinstance(param2, basestring):
        # implementation 1
     elif isinstance(param1, basestring) and isinstance(param2, list):
        # implementation 2
     elif ...

     else:
         raise TypeError
```

Is this the best way to do it? I am new in python.

Thanks.

Comment: well if the algorithm differs depending on the type then *maybe* you shouldn't be using 1 function but 2, where 1 deals with a single instance and another deals with a list of instances.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Duck typing means testing for methods, not using `isinstance()`. What do you intend to *do* with the input?

If, for example, you'll accept a string, then split that string on newlines and use it otherwise like a list, test for `.splitlines()`:

```
if hasattr(arg1, 'splitlines'):
    arg1 = arg1.splitlines()
if hasattr(arg2, 'splitlines'):
    arg2 = arg2.splitlines()
# now arg1 and arg2 are presumed to be lists.
```

Comment: I would argue the better way is to try and do ``arg1.splitlines()`` and catch the exception if it fails - or try using it as a list, then, if it fails, try using ``splitlines()``.

Comment: @Lattyware: *that* depends entirely on frequency of use. See [Python Forgiveness vs. Permission and Duck Typing](http://programmers.stackexchange.com/questions/175655/175663#175663)

Comment: @MartijnPieters The parameters are two filenames or lists of filenames and I need to process the second parameter file/s with information of the first parameter file/s. So regarding your answer one solution could be to create a list with the string parameter and work always with lists.